# Why did Caesar let Law in Punk Hazard?

Tags: one-piece

He had some gains from this, as Law used his medical abilities and the power of the devil's fruit to restore the limbs in the inhabitants of the island.

But Law told him to not inform Doflamingo of the fact that he is staying there.
(Later i would see that Doflamingo an Law had been enemies for years)

Didn't this alarm Caesar? What are the reasons that Caesar believed, Law would want to stay in Punk Hazard?

He didn't question Laws agenda or motivations at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons Law told Ceasar:

> I'm looking into research that the government is carrying out. This facility should contain valuable traces of research that is still going on to this day.

(chapter 666, page 5)

Ceasar's exact reaction was:

> I don't see how I can trust you, but I suppose your proposition can't hurt

(chapter 666, page 6)

So Law's story checked out, he didn't seem like a threat, and even though he wasn't trusted, Ceasar thought he would benefit from keeping Law around.

Comment: I saw that chapter. But Ceasar and Monet were present in that discussion. They were both Doflamingo's underlings. Didn't they know the past between Law and Doflamingo? Didn't they know Law was wanted by Dofalmingo? Given that Law was a sichibukai, they should know that this sichibukai is wanted by Doflamingo? Also, isn't this move of not reporting to Doflamingo a sort of betrayal or at least taking their own initiative from both Ceasar and Monet?

Comment: Doflamingo doesn't share all his information with all of his underlings. If he did, then Corazon would be still alive.

Comment: How Corazon would be alive?

Comment: (OK, that's really only my speculation, and also totally irrelevant to the question/answer, but I think if Corazon knew about Vergo infiltrating the marines, then either him or Sengoku could've taken care of him before he caused any trouble.)

Comment: This is a smart thing to speculate. Seems absolutely probable. But i still cannot come to terms with the fact that Doflamingo's underlings didn't know he had a grudge with Law. This is especially more so, considering Law's popularity as a Sichibukai.

Comment: It's not a grudge. It's not personal, it's about getting the Ope-Ope no mi. (And telling that to people just invites more competition.) And not letting him get the fruit wasn't Law's fault, it was Corazon's.